# How to ensure element id is set even if field value is blank?

Tags: java, gwt, qtp

I am setting ids of `GWT` widgets using code like the following:

```
quoteNumberTextBox.getElement().setId("quoteNumberTextBox");
```

This works well if the field has a value.  But if it does not have a value, `QTP` is not able to locate the element `id`.

Any thoughts on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Use quoteNumberTextBox.ensureDebugId("quoteNumberTextBox") .It will work

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the TextBox widget does not actually create the DOM element returned by getElement()until it has a value.  You could set the value to a blank space before calling the .setId  method.